# UIWebView not showing properly on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am building a very simple application for iphone and ipad with a UIWebView which load site, but there is an issue, it is working properly on iphone but on iPad the site moved upward and is even not scrollable.

Following are the screenshots:

iphone:

[image: iphone screenshot]

ipad:

[image: ipad screenshot]

You can see the header section on ipad is not visible, please help me.

here is .m file code

```
UIWebView *myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,myView.frame.size.width,myView.frame.size.height)];
myWebView.delegate = self;
myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.webhousemedia.com/?";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
myWebView.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
[self.view addSubview:myWebView];
```

Comment: `myWebView.frame = self.view.bounds;`

Comment: Just check your Autosizing for Layout in xib for iPad.

Comment: did you try with some other Website, same code ? i just open the site in the Safari, it opens exactly as same as iPad, and when i resize the safari browser, its getting changes, perhaps problem might be the JS of the site,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try this..

UIWebView *myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height)];
```